# unable to connect to any IRC server using irssi

Tags: ssl, glib, irc, irssi

I am using irssi 1.2.3 (20210409 0011). When I do `/connect Freenode` (or any server for that matter), I get the following error.

```
GLib warning SSL handshake failed: server closed connection unexpectedly
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you connect to IRC with any other clients? Can you connect over a non-SSL port?

Comment: I tried with hexchat, and Konversation, both of them show `network unreachable`. I can't connect over a non-SSL port too.

Comment: Does the Internet otherwise work from that computer? What ISP does it have? Does connecting to IRC work if you use a proxy, a VPN, or Tor?

Comment: I can use the internet on that machine. I tried with a VPN and I can connect to servers.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to servers that are *not* part of Freenode?

Comment: I took it with the ISP and was able to resolve it. I did not check servers other than Freenode and OFTC, but I guess all would have been unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the clarification in your comments, it seems that someone is intentionally trying to block your access to IRC. If you don't want using a VPN to be your permanent solution, then this is something that you'll need to take up with them. If you're at home and in charge of your own router (and you didn't just set up the block yourself and then forget you did so), then "someone" is probably your ISP, and if you're somewhere else, then "someone" is probably that place's IT group.

Comment: Understood. I will take this up with my ISP. Thanks a lot!